# WebSocket server in c# not connecting

Tags: c#, websocket

Im trying to make a WebSocket server, but it never connects. I use This website as a client

https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

On that page in the box i put this

ws://1.2.3.4:8888

1.2.3.4 is not the real ip address i just put that in here as a place holder instead of putting my real IP address. But it never connects

Then the C# code below as the server, the code below is the whole program, but no matter what i do it never connects, i have a break point at the OnOpen in the C# code it never hits, and there are no errors or exceptions generated.

I have the port 8888 open in the firewall, and i can connect to that same port using regular sockets from Java to a different C# program i have running on the same server.

Does anybody know why it doesnt connect?

Thanks

```
using Fleck;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<IWebSocketConnection> sockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
        Fleck.WebSocketServer server = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:8888");

        server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection open.");
                sockets.Add(socket);
            };
            socket.OnClose = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
                sockets.Remove(socket);
            };
            socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client Says: " + message);
                sockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(" client says: " + message));

            };
        });

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != "exit") {
            sockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(input));
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with cross site configuration (CORS) etc, or some other thing i dont know about?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, no exception,nothing, it never calls the OnOpen. I dont know what to do.